# Problema para obtener solo div de Data en JavaScript asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Buenas tengo esto para hacer append a una lista de productos que se actualiza cada vez que se baja lo suficiente el scroll:

```
function (data) {
                    /*
                    *  Añadimos la información obtenida (data) dentro del contenedor (#contenedor-catalogo).
                    */
                    $("#contenedor-catalogo").append(data);
                    console.log(data);

                    viewModel.lastLoadedPage(viewModel.currentPage());
                 }
```

lo que trae el data es toda la vista parcial, quiero saber si puedo sacar solo una parte de la vista (por decir un div), ya que al traerme toda la vista me duplica los actionlinks que tengo (creo que está es la razón, o si alguien sabe si es por otra cosa me lo puede decir, por favor).

Esto es lo que trae la data:

```
<div id="here">
<div class="container animated fadeIn">

    <!--Inicia sección menú de ordenación-->
    <ul class="list-inline order-items" style="margin:10px;">
        @{ var defaultType = "btn-default";
            var selectedType = "btn-primary";
            var auxType = defaultType;
        }
        <li><span>Ordenar por:</span></li>
        <li>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Nombre", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = "name", pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = @ViewBag.orderType, MostrarImagen = @TempData["MostrarImagen"] }, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading-container", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "here", OnSuccess = "loadImages()", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn " + ((ViewBag.OrderBy != null && ViewBag.OrderBy != "" && ViewBag.OrderBy != "name") ? defaultType : selectedType) + " btn-xs js-data-order btn-order _default", @data_order_id = "name" })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Categoría", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = "category", pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = @ViewBag.orderType, MostrarImagen = @TempData["MostrarImagen"] }, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading-container", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "here", OnSuccess = "loadImages()", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn " + ((ViewBag.OrderBy == null) ? defaultType : (ViewBag.OrderBy == "category") ? selectedType : defaultType) + " btn-xs js-data-order btn-order", @data_order_id = "category" })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Precio", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = "price", pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = @ViewBag.orderType, MostrarImagen = @TempData["MostrarImagen"] }, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading-container", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "here", OnSuccess = "loadImages()", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn " + ((ViewBag.OrderBy == null) ? defaultType : (ViewBag.OrderBy == "price") ? selectedType : defaultType) + " btn-xs js-data-order btn-order", @data_order_id = "price" })
        </li>
        @Html.Hidden("OrderBy", (object)ViewBag.OrderBy)
        @Html.Hidden("OrderType", (object)ViewBag.orderType)
        <li><span>Modo:</span></li>
        <li>
            @{ auxType = (@ViewBag.orderType == "" || @ViewBag.orderType.ToLower() == "asc") ? selectedType : defaultType; }
            @Ajax.ActionLink("asc", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = @ViewBag.OrderBy, pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = "asc", MostrarImagen = @TempData["MostrarImagen"] }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "here", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn " + auxType + " btn-xs btn-ordertype _default" })
            <!--<a class="btn @auxType btn-xs btn-ordertype _default" data-ordertype-id="Asc" href="#">Asc</a>-->

            @{ auxType = (@ViewBag.orderType.ToLower() == "desc") ? selectedType : defaultType; }
            @Ajax.ActionLink("desc", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = @ViewBag.OrderBy, pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = "desc", MostrarImagen = @TempData["MostrarImagen"] }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "here", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn " + auxType + " btn-xs btn-ordertype _default" })
            <!--<a class="btn @auxType btn-xs btn-ordertype" data-ordertype-id="Desc" href="#">Desc</a>-->

        </li>

        <li><span>Mostrar Imagenes:</span></li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBox("MostrarImagen", true, new { @onchange = "OnValueChanged();" })
        </li>

    </ul>


    <ul class="breadcrumb detallesCss">
        <li><a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'>Inicio</a></li>

        <li class="active">Catálogo</li>
    </ul>
</div><hr />

<!--Contenedor catálogo-->
<div class="container">

    <!--Sección listado catálogos-->
    <div class="flex-row row" id="contenedor-catalogo">
        @{
            if (!Model.Any())
            {
                <div class='alert alert-warning col-xs-12 errorMessage animated fadeIn fast'>
                    Por El Momento No Existen Más Productos Disponibles
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-3 producto-item animated fadeIn fast">
                        <div class="card">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("detail", "Productos", new { id = item.EntidadId, name = item.Nombre.ToUrlSeo() })">

                                @if (!ViewBag.MostrarImagen)
                                {
                                    <img class="card-img-top catalogo-imagen" src="" data-src="/Productos/image/@item.EntidadId" data-pending="true" onerror="imgError(this);" style="display:none">
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img class="card-img-top catalogo-imagen" src="" data-src="/Productos/image/@item.EntidadId" data-pending="true" onerror="imgError(this);" style="display:normal">
                                }

                            </a>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h4 class="card-title">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("detail", "Productos", new { id = item.EntidadId, name = item.Nombre.ToUrlSeo()})">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="meta">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">

                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Categoria)

                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-text">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-text">
                                    Precio:
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrecioUnitario)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            }

        }
    </div>

    @* Contenedor que incluye Loader 1 y el componente para mostrar los mensajes de error. *@
    <div class="container-result">
        <div id="pre-loader"><div class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' style='font-size:24px'></i></div></div>
        <div style="display:none;" id="error-msg"><p>Ocurrío un error al obtener la información.</p></div>
    </div>

</div>

<!--remove float-->
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<!-- Loader 2 -->
<div id="loading-container" style="display:none;text-align:center;width: 100%;height: 100%;opacity: 0.6;position: fixed;background-color: white;top: 70px;left: 0;margin: 0 auto;z-index: 9999;"></div>
```

entonces resumiendo, lo que quiero hacer es obtener de data solo el div que tiene como id contenedor-catalogo, alguien me puede ayudar con esto?, o si no es lo mas optimo que podría hacer para evitar que me coloque de nuevo los actionlinks? (cuando presiono los actionlinks remplaza los botones sin problemas, pero al hacer el evento scrooll los vuelve a poner).

Este es el evento de movimiento de scroll:

```
function ajaxMovement(queryParams, beforeSend, onSuccess, onError) {

$.ajax({
    url: "Productos/Index" + document.location.search,  //URL del recurso
    type: "post",  //Se define el método POST como verbo de solicitud.
    contentType: "text/html",  //La respuesta vendrá en formato text/html
    data: queryParams, //Los parámetros están definidos en la URL destino, por lo cual la propiedad 'data' se envía como vacía.
    beforeSend: function () {
        if (beforeSend != null)
            beforeSend();
    }
}).then(function (data) {

    if (!data.includes("errorMessage"))
        //Mostramos AJAX loader
        $(".container-result  #pre-loader").show();
    else
        $(".container-result  #pre-loader").hide();

    //Ocultamos los mensajes de error
    $(".container-result  #error-msg").hide();

    if (onSuccess != null)
        onSuccess(data);



    loadImages();

}, function (error) {

    //Ocultar componente AJAX loader
    $(".container-result  #pre-loader").hide();

    //Mostrar mensaje de error.
    $(".container-result  #error-msg").show();

    if (onError != null)
        onError(error);

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al siguiente enlace puede solucionarlo
https://www.oipapio.com/question-6082903

Se soluciona utilizando lo siguiente:
jQuery(data).find('#contenedor-catalogo').html().